# How to open .bpr files and build a project?

Tags: c++, c, borland-c++, borland-c

I have a .bpr file in a downloaded project.
Is there any application that can build the project based on this file.

I think it relates to old borland C age.

The previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794578/14039503) is referring to a dead link.

Comment: Yes it's an old Borland project file. Unless modern version of the IDE can open it, you have to resort to piracy for an old version. Not something I recommend. What I *do* recommend is that you throw it all away, and keep looking for modern and more up to date example projects.

Comment: Piracy (OR) maybe use the `strings` command to maybe recover some data from the file ?

Comment: No piracy, Borland (now Embarcadero) gave away lots of dinosaurware for free, maybe 15 years ago. This program is so ancient that even the "Borland museum" that showcased it has withered away into dust.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude “*Unless modern version of the IDE can open it*” - they can. However, such an old project likely has references that are outdated and would need to be updated/replaced. Generally, it is not a good idea to open an old project in a new IDE, but to create a new project in the new IDE and add existing source files to it as needed.